# How to prove that a graph A is a subgraph of graph B?

Tags: graph-theory

From the definition of a subgraph:

> A graph whose vertices and edges are subsets of another graph.

Source: https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/subgraph.html

However, I am not able to apply it on the actual graphs.

Suppose I have 2 graphs (please see the images), how to prove that the  [graph B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj0Uj.jpg) is the subgraph of [graph A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezlOQ.jpg).

Comment: You probably mean to ask about $B$ being *isomorphic to a subgraph of* $A$.  Otherwise, the labeling of the vertices and edges comes into play.  As for *proving* that $B$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $A$... that is simple.  Just come up with a labeling for the vertices and edges of graph $A$ and a labeling of the vertices and edges of the graph $B$ such that the labelings and adjacencies for all of the vertices and edges in $B$ coincide with how they appear in $A$.  What you are left with is an explicit pen-and-paper representation of $A$ and $B$ in terms of sets after which it is trivial.

Comment: @an4s Noted with thanks. I looked at the post. However, is it possible to explain wrt the above images. That post is very good and also generalized. But as a beginner I want to start with a small example. Hope you understand.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am sorry but there was no mention of "isomorphic". It was an example given after the definition of subgraph.

Comment: Well, what you shared as images aren't *graphs* per se... they are unlabeled graphs.  Had the vertices in your graph $A$ been labeled $x,y,z,u,v$ while the vertices in graph $B$ been labeled $1,2,3,4$ then $B$ would *not* be a subgraph of $A$.  The vertex set of $B$ wouldn't even intersect the vertex set of $A$.  It will however be *isomorphic* to a subgraph of $A$.

Comment: @JMoravitz So, if the graphs are not labeled, we can't say whether one is a subgraph of the other. Please confirm. And thanks for explaining the "isomorphic" relationship between two graphs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us begin by choosing a labeling of the graphs in question

[image]

[image]

Now... these images are merely graphical pictoral *representations* of the actual underlying mathematical objects being discussed.  Recall that a graph is technically a pair of sets $G = (V,E)$ where $V$ is the set of vertices and $E$ the set of edges, recalling that $E$ is a subset of $V\times V$.

Writing out these graphs in terms of the sets they represent we have:

$$B = (\{\color{blue}{1,2,3,4}\},\{\color{red}{\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}}\})$$

and

$$A = (\{\color{blue}{1,2,3,4},5\},\{\{1,2\},\color{red}{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}},\{2,4\},\color{red}{\{3,4\}},\{4,5\}\})$$

From here, it is clear to see that $\{\color{blue}{1,2,3,4}\}\subseteq \{\color{blue}{1,2,3,4},5\}$ so the vertex set of $B$ is indeed a subset of the vertex set of $A$ as well as $\{\color{red}{\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{3,4\}}\}\subseteq 
\{\{1,2\},\color{red}{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}},\{2,4\},\color{red}{\{3,4\}},\{4,5\}\}$ so the edge set of $B$ is a subset of the edge set of $A$.  This, following from the basic definitions of what it means to be a subset of.  $X$ is considered a subset of $Y$ iff every element of $X$ (*if any exist in the first place*) is also an element of $Y$.

If the labelings of the graphs were different, we could be in a situation where officially the one would *not* be a subgraph of the other.  It could however be *isomorphic* to a subgraph of the other.  To be isomorphic to a subgraph of the other, that just means that there is a way to relabel the vertices and edges in such a way as to make it an actual subgraph of the other.  Since you appear to be working with unlabeled graphs, it is not uncommon to drop the "isomorphic to" aspect of the phrase since this is the only possible interpretation, effectively requiring you to choose a labeling of *both* graphs before continuing.

I will point out that the task of actually *finding* a relabeling of the edges and vertices such that the one graph is a subgraph of the other is a "difficult" problem (*Specifically, it is a NP-complete problem*).  It is possible that one choice of labels don't work but a different choice of labels would have worked.  In our specific case, there was a clear choice of labels to use since the images used for the two graphs were so similar.  In the generalized problem it might not be clear at all.

For techniques, algorithms, and more information on the fully generalized problem, see [Subgraph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) on wikipedia.

Comment: Great explanation and use of colours!!!

Comment: Thanks a ton for your efforts!